# Select Statement not working properly

Tags: android, sqlite

I have an application consisting of two buttons and a text view.

- `btnInsert` : when the user clicks this, an insert statement will be performed
- `btnShow` : a select statement will be executed and the result is displayed in the TextView.

The problem is the following.  I am using AsyncTask to perform write / read operations.  I created two separate AsyncTasks, one for reading, one for writing.  The insert (Write Async works properly, and I am sure that the values are getting inserted because if I run the same insert statement twice I get a PRIMARY KEY violation error:

```
07-19 11:46:48.080: E/AndroidRuntime(21486): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-19 11:46:48.080: E/AndroidRuntime(21486): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: PRIMARY KEY must be unique (code 19)
```

This is where the problem arises.  Everything is performed properly, apparently, when I run the Select Statement ( by clicking the button), however instead of the value, I get `com.example.testdb.MainActivity$Select@4203e900`.

Does anyone know what the problem is? It is very annoying, I do not know what I am doing wrong.  Please have a look at my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
static DatabaseImplementation db;
static SQLiteDatabase dbWrite;
static SQLiteDatabase dbRead;

static String insert = "INSERT INTO tbl_Test VALUES(7, 'Test');";
static String select = "SELECT test FROM tbl_Test WHERE _id = 1;";

Button btnInsert;
Button btnShow;
static TextView txtView;

//static String name = "";


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    db = new DatabaseImplementation(this);
    dbWrite = db.getWritableDatabase();
    dbRead = db.getReadableDatabase();

    txtView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtView);

    btnInsert = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnInsert);
    btnInsert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            new Insert().execute();
        }
    });

    btnShow = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnShow);
    btnShow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
             AsyncTask<String, Void, String> n = new Select().execute();
             txtView.setText(n.toString());
        }
    });


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

//INSERT ASYNC
private class Insert extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{       
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params)
    {

        //Connect to Database First.
        try
        {       
            //String insert = executeInsert();
            //onPostExecute(insert);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
    {

        //Connect to Database First.
        dbWrite.execSQL(insert);
    }


}

//SELECT ASYNC
private class Select extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params)
    {
        try
        {
            dbWrite = db.getWritableDatabase();
            Cursor c = dbWrite.rawQuery(select, null);

            String name = "";
            c.moveToFirst();
            name = c.getString(0);

            return name;

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
    {

    }   
}
```

}

I would really appreciate if someone could help me.

Comment: Have you considered using an ORM? This kind of DB access seems very unstable to me.

Comment: I should try that out sometime, thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That has nothing to do with the database but just with this two lines:

```
AsyncTask<String, Void, String> n = new Select().execute();
txtView.setText(n.toString());
```

Variable `n` is of tyoe `AsyncTask`, and applying `toString()` on it therefore gives you just the name of the class like you described (`com.example.testdb.MainActivity$Select@4203e900`).

What you got to do is, to change the `onPostExecute()` method of your `Select` class to this:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
{
    txtView.setText(result);
}
```

and remove the line `txtView.setText(n.toString());` from your onClick handler.